# Rotate vector relative to another rotated vector

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, rotation

I have a vector `v = <0,0,-1>` and four other vectors that form a "square" at z-index of `-1` with side length `2*s`, such that the four vectors are:

- `OA = <-s, s, -1>`
- `OB = < s, s, -1>`
- `OC = <-s,-s, -1>`
- `OD = < s,-s, -1>`

Now, consider point `P` anywhere in the 3D space.

I want to rotate `v` in such a way that it aligns with the position vector `OP` of point `P`, and then apply rotations to the other four vectors such that all four vectors stick together in the same relative position from `v`.

In other words, the whole "pyramid" of vectors needs to be rotated so that `v` and `OP` align.

[Screenshot of scenario](https://cldup.com/wfdBaFSseC.png).

The point `P` is arbitrary and can be any point in the 3D space. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this question should be asked rather at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com. You should precise that if I understand correctly you want to rotate a shape ABCD around the point O.

Comment: Forgive me. I've seen math-related question here on SO. I'll copy the question over. Thanks

Comment: @Mekku if you do, please delete it from here.

Comment: [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) has a [Quaternion](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Quaternion.html) class template that does this, in case you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Wintermute I've already tried working with quaternions, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around them. If I have the quaternion rotation to rotate the middle vector `v` into `OP`, can the same rotation be applied to the the other four vectors?

Comment: Exactly so (this would also be the case with a rotation matrix). With Eigen, you can just say `Eigen::Quaterniond R = Eigen::Quaterniond::FromTwoVectors(v, OP); Eigen::Vector3d a_rotated = R * a;` Note that the rotation from `v` to `OP` is not unique, and that only rotation happens even if `v` and `P` have different lengths (i.e., no upscaling or anything).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is to late to answer since you are moving the question, but your question is quite heavily used in 3D graphics work. You should look at the wikipedia article for Rotation Matrix and a good article [Rotation About an Arbitrary Axis in 3D](http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/). Both of those should give you the understanding of how to manipulate a vector or matrix in 3D.

Comment: For what I have understood, rotating about an axis does not solve his problem.

Comment: I think you are correct @coincoin. The OP wants to know how to rotate in a 3D system, not about a single axis. The article I linked explains how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to rotate your shape ABCD around the point O with the constraint that (OP) and (OV) are aligned.

I think of one way to simply do that algorithmitically without the need to compute any transformations or rotations. Let  V',A',B',C',D' be your new points.

1/
Place a point V' such that :

```
-->   ||VO||   -->
V'O = ------ . OP
      ||OP||
```

This should not be hard since you know O, P, and V.

2/
Vectors V'O or OP are normal to the plane A',B',C',D'. So you can place the latter points on this plane so that they form a square and include V' as a middle. Some maths are needed here (if interested I can deepen the explanations).

Hope you are allowed to do it this way.
As commented before you better ask maybe http://scicomp.stackexchange.com for nice mathematical solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this but thanks for takign the time to answer. I've moved the question to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/. Should I delete the question from here as suggested?

Comment: I am not sure now if you had not understood this it would surely be harder to understand over there. What have you not understood ?  (I will try to update my answer)

Comment: I think it's a matter of not having explained myself properly, since the assumption that `VO /\ V'O = 0` is what really confused me.

Comment: I tried to edit for being I hope more understandable. Hope that can help but your question involves some maths background if you want it to make it work for any P.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand what you're doing. You're creating vector `V'O` as a portion of `OP` and using it as a normal to the plane. Thanks for the edit. My brain's tired from all the math. I'll give this a shot